# Sending struct with dyamic array of string to c++ dll from c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I have a struct defined as

```
struct DiskInfo{
int size,
char **atributes
};
```

I need to sent it to c++ dll that will run something like

```
for(i=0;i<Files.count;i++)
{
   newList[i] = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeof(List->Strings[i]));  
   wcscpy(newList[i], List->Strings[i]);
  .... more code
 }
```

At this point I have the struct poplutaed will all the data, and i need to send it back to c#.
I tried:

```
internal struct DiskInfo
    {
        internal int size;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
        internal string[] Files;
    }
```

and the signature is

```
[DllImport("Disk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = GetDiskInfo")]
    internal static extern uint GetDiskInfo(
       [In, Out] 
        DiskInfo Param);
```

And call to function

```
 data= new DiskInfo();
 Native.GetDiskInfo(data);
```

However, data is always returned as null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. The C++ and C# structs shown here have different names, different member order, and the C++ version doesn't contain a "ByVal" array. Are these supposed to be the same structs?

Comment: fixed itm yes, they are the same struct

Answer (score 1):

In C#, DiskInfo is a struct, which means that it is a value type, and will be passed into a method by copying (unless the ref keyword is used).  So the C++ code can't possibly modify the original struct, only the copy.  You might have better luck if you declared GetDiskInfo with the ref keyword and also used that keyword in your method call.